# An Exocentric compound for Children

Tags: word-choice, nouns, compounds

I have written a story for children in Persian. Somewhere in the story, I have mentioned "pear". "Pear" In Farsi is *gool-abbi*, which translates literally as "blue flower". I have mentioned that as something that is neither blue nor a flower. Now I am about to translate the book into English and am looking for an exocentric compound in English that a 6- or 7-year-old English-speaking child can understand easily.

Comment: A little confused about what you are asking here. Are you asking for an exocentric compound that means "pear"?

Comment: @pavja2: I suspect he means something like the "Holy Roman Empire" which was said not to be holy, Roman or an empire.  But something children would appreciate.

Comment: How about "pineapple"?

Comment: @pavja2 not at all, looking for something with the same functionality structure-wise

Comment: Lovely question, and thank-you for introducing me to the terms exocentric and endocentric.

Comment: @StoneyB This is indeed a nice suggestion, though I am not sure  that "pine" is as easily understood as "blue" and "flower" by children? Of course, I don't know English speaking children as much as you do.

Comment: Well, it certainly would in the US South, where pine is the dominant tree.

Comment: @AmirAsghari Christmas trees are pines; even in parts of the US where they're not commonly grown I'd expect almost all children to know what they are.

Comment: @StoneyB Go to the Northwest. Pines are *everywhere*.

Comment: @DanNeely: That's odd. Around here (northern Europe) Christmas trees are pretty much invariably spruces. (Except when they're plastic, that is.)

Comment: @DanNeely Though "pineapple" somehow works for my purpose, I'd like to add that it seems Christmas trees are just Christmas trees not pines! My daughter spent her primary school years in England and she is a lover of Christmas. When I asked her if she knows what "pine" means, it took a few seconds until she doubtfully guessed it is a kind of tree!

Comment: @IlmariKaronen In general conversation I know very few people who make the distinction between pines, firs, spruce, etc.  eg "We cut down the pine tree for Christmas yesterday."  "What kind?"  "A blue spruce."

Comment: ^this. "Pine tree" is used casually in America to mean most any evergreen.

Comment: I just read about [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_plurals#Headless_nouns) in Wikipedia. Is it the same as what is being discussed here?

Comment: In the Wikipedia link it's called **Headless noun**

Comment: @StoneyB a pineapple actually *is* an apple. *Apple* in its older meaning "fruit".

Comment: This seems like an awfully specific requirement for a translation. Most words, not matter how metaphorical they are in derivation, are not understood with that history in mind. A pineapple is not understood to be literally a pine-like apple (or however pine is involved). A pineapple is understood literally to be that yellow tropical fruit with the bark -like exterior. Is it important to the story that the word be misunderstood pun-like through its parts?

Answer (score 16):

One suggestion would be *buttercup*, which is neither butter (though it is yellow) nor a cup (though I suppose the flower is vaguely cup-shaped).

Answer (score 11):

The line between endocentric and exocentric compounds is [not always clear](http://linguistlist.org/ask-ling/message-details1.cfm?asklingid=200322625). For example, word meanings change. Today, a *footprint* is neither a *foot* nor a *print*, but *print* referred originally to any kind of mark or stamp, and thus *footprint* would have been endocentric. In other cases, the component retains its meaning as a standalone word, but it is overshadowed by a more common usage. A *screwdriver* is neither a *screw* nor a *driver*, in the sense of *driver* as the operator of a vehicle, but then *driver* refers to something which impels, as a screwdriver certainly does. And many compounds are analogies to begin with. An *oxbow* lake is neither an *ox* nor a *bow*, but was named because it is the same shape as a type of collar for an ox. Still other words appear to be compounds, but are not: *polemarch* is borrowed from ancient Greek, not from the union of *pole* and *march*. And so there is room to argue about the suitability of words like *railroad*, *doughnut*, *headphone*, *skyscraper*, *gumdrop*, and many others.

For children, it may be good enough to stick to contemporary uses, in which case I think the following should be uncontroversial:

Animals: *butterfly*, *dragonfly*, *firefox*, *hedgehog*, *polecat*, *seahorse*

Plants/flowers: *bluebell*, *catnip*, *forget-me-not*, *honeydew*, *pineapple*, *snapdragon*

Objects/Materials: *cardboard*, *dreadnought*, *matchbook*, *moonshine*, *sawdust*, *touchstone*, *turtleneck*, *wardrobe*

People: *birdbrain*, *egghead*, *litterbug*, *pickpocket*

Activities: *brainstorm*, *fanfare*, *hogwash*, *honeymoon*, *potluck*, *shorthand*

Places: *carport*, *speakeasy*

Other: *humdrum*

Comment: Many thanks indeed. Your answer was an excellent lesson for me, and now, I have plenty to choose from.

Comment: Actually, I would describe all your _animal_ examples as endocentric but metaphorical. A _butterfly_ is not literally a _fly_, it is true, but it is something like a kind of fly. Ditto for _pineapple_ and _matchbook_. This is a quite different semantic process from most of the other words: _catnip_ does not in any way resemble a kind of _nip_ (indeed, I don't know what that would mean). I would describe only the latter class as exocentric.

Comment: @ColinFine I would agree that *exocentric* and *endocentric* as used by scholars would be stricter (thus also excluding e.g. *carport*), but I think the OP is not after "exocentric" so much as, as Rendall put it, "an *xy* which is neither *x* nor *y*."

Comment: @ColinFine The main character of the story that I have mentioned has a name that does not match with what it is. This fact bothers it and it tries to calm itself by thinking of other things having the same difficulty. That's what I am looking for: those other things!

Comment: @AmirAsghari Note that some of the examples here are unlikely to be understood by young children and some of them are specific to particular dialects or variants. (So they might be understood by 6 and 7 year olds on one side of the Atlantic but only by older children or adults on the other since they might be more familiar with other variants of English.) Some of those terms are unfamiliar to adult speakers of British English, for example, and there are terms which I recognise as American but can't currently remember the meaning of even though I lived there for a decade. (cf. 'ladybird'!)

Comment: Hmmm … _footprint_ is quite endocentric to me. It _is_ a kind of print.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'm thinking I should simply remove any reference to *exocentric* and *endocentric* altogether. *Footprint* (indeed, *fingerprint* and so on) would work for the OP, endocentric or not, as it is clearly not a *[print](http://www.bedbathandbeyond.com/store/product/van-gogh-irises-in-the-garden-gallery-wrap-canvas-print/1041757123)* in the sense of a mass-printed reproduction of a painting or photograph.

Comment: It’s not a type of print in that sense, no. But it _is_ a type of print. I don’t think it ‘counts’ as “not a type of _x_ or _y_” just because _y_ also has another definition. _Shaving cream_ is still a type of cream even though it’s never been near a cow’s udder, and a _criminal offence_ is still a type of offence even though no one felt offended.

Comment: *Firefox?* I found [this Wkipedia redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox_(animal)), but before that I only knew the web browser name. So that one could be seen as "controversial" for children. (A bit like asking kids to spell a [word whose sole raison d'être seems to be raising the spelling bee bar](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/174141/)! :)

Answer (score 11):

***Mushroom*** was a word which I loved as a small child, there is no *room* in *mush* [1](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mush)
A type of mushroom is a ***toadstool***, which is neither a frog nor a type of chair or poo (stool)

And there is the silly old pun which still raises a smile.

Q: *Why did the Mushroom get invited to all the parties*?
A: *Because he's a fungi!* (fun guy)

Q: *Why did the fungi leave the party?*
A: *There wasn't mushroom.*

OR

Q: *Why do toadstools grow so closely together?*
A: *Because they don't need mushroom*

Comment: Your jokes are in spore taste.  ;)

Answer (score 8):

Here are a group of compound words that can fit in the form "An xy is neither x nor y"

peanut (not a nut, but a legume)
tadpole
gumdrop
honeydew
ladyfingers
pancake
pineapple
earwig
drumstick
snapdragon
cupboard

Comment: A peanut is not a nut, but is arguably a pea. It's part of the same [subfamily of plants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faboideae) as the pea, the sweet pea, the chick pea, the black-eyed pea, etc.

Comment: Of course a peanut is a nut—colloquially speaking. You find it with the other nuts in supermarkets, in bags with mixed nuts, etc. In common parlance, a peanut is a type of nut. Its exact botanical taxonomy is irrelevant. Strawberries, blackberries, raspberries, and many others are not berries, either; but they’re still berries in normal usage. I’d also call a pancake endocentric—it is a type of cake, albeit an unusual one.

Comment: _Tadpole_, _earwig_, and _snapdragon_ are like good suggestions. The others seem to be exocentric only if one is overly-literal.

Comment: A snapdragon is not a dragon?!?!?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - you'll often find raisins in bags of mixed nuts. Doesn't make them nuts. The distinction between peanuts and true nuts is quite important to people who are allergic to one or the other (or indeed both). But that wasn't the main point of my comment, which was that the assertion "an xy is neither x nor y" does not seem to apply where xy=peanut.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't see **grapefruit** listed. While it is a fruit, it has nothing to do with grapes. Do both parts of the compound word have to be contradictory?

Comment: [The Library of Congress](http://www.loc.gov/rr/scitech/mysteries/grapefruit.html) says, “It is believed that the name refers to the manner in which grapefruit grows in clusters on a tree.” I found that site at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grapefruit#History).

Comment: I've always found "grapefruit" a particularly bizarre name. I can understand, say, [breadfruit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadfruit) because you're saying "it's like bread, but it's a fruit". With grapefruit you're saying, "it's like a grape, but it's a fruit". Yet grapes are already a fruit!

Answer (score 3):

I see other people are submitting half answers, so here are a few more:

- A “hot dot” is not a dog (and it needn’t be hot).
- A “hamburger” isn’t (supposed to be) made of ham.<sup>1</sup>
- While “strawberries” are berries, they have nothing to do with straw. 
  (Except if they do; see discussions at [Yahoo! Answers](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080704115704AACgtft) and [Buzzle](http://www.buzzle.com/articles/history-of-strawberries.html),
  with a dissenting minority report at [Snopes](http://www.snopes.com/language/notthink/strawberry.asp).)
- You go to the “bathroom” for other reasons than to take a bath. 
  Very few bathrooms contain bath tubs. 
  (This one may be specific to American English.)
- And conversely, for the un-Americans (☺), “water closet”,
  which isn’t very much like any other closet.

---

<sup>1</sup> A slightly amusing anecdote that might be a better fit on ELL: 
I know somebody from India, so English is his second (at least) language,
and he’s a vegetarian. 
He knows what (ham)burgers are,
and he knows that a “veggie-burger” is a burger made of vegetables
– so he once ordered a “cheeseburger”,
expecting it to be a vegetarian burger made of cheese and other non-meat products.

Comment: In Holland, there are lots of houses with a WC where other houses have a closet: [under](http://www.w2bouw.nl/w2bouw/media/Map-algemeen-2011/09w2toilet1.jpg) [the](http://www.welke.nl/photo/Ellen10/Mooie-wc-onder-de-trap.1373802641) [stairs](http://www.mijnalbum.nl/Foto-BN8ADZAX.jpg).

Comment: Hamburg-er, like frankfurt-er, originally denoted a German city of origin, not the content of the food.

Answer (score 3):

If you're targeting British children then *ladybird* works quite nicely. Unfortunately the Americans more sensibly call it a *ladybug*.

6- and 7-year-olds might also like *shampoo*; it's up to you whether you feel that lowers the tone of your book too much.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest an [alligator pear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avocado), which is neither an alligator (though it's green), nor a pear (though it's pear-shaped).

Comment: I can't imagine any 7 year olds have ever heard of an alligator pear. I certainly haven't.

Answer (score 1):

The *love apple* is a still-acceptable synonym for the tomato.

Not an apple, and I for one don't love them.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a nice word for what you are describing would be "Pumpkin".  English speakers often use it as an endearing nickname, although it is a discreet type of fruit that comes from a romance root meaning "large melon".

Answer (score 1):

I've been racking my brains for days, knowing there was a word whose apparent etymology was nonsense, that had amused me as a child.

At last it came to me: a *carpet* is neither a car nor a pet, nor indeed anything remotely to do with with either of them.

Comment: Though magic carpet somehow is a kind of car! :)

Comment: One you can keep as a pet, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Children of that age would probably be familiar with jokes that rely on a *sandwich* being neither *sand* nor a *witch*. The spelling's not perfect, but I think it works well enough.